# What is the significance of Palmistry prop hand in Michael Jennings house?

Tags: analysis, props, paycheck

In *Paycheck*, we see a Palmistry prop hand in Michael Jennings house:

[image]

But reverse engineer and this thing in his house seems little out of context.
Is it some foreshadowing element about the future prediction machine or the machine itself based on palmistry?